# Getting the 'request' within Class Based View

Tags: django

I'm attempting to subclass the LoginView so that I can change the template_name that is part of LoginView. I've simplified my template_file_name function for the purposes of this example.

```
def template_file_name(request, template_name, page_title):
   return template_name


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):    
   template_name = template_file_name(self.request, 'login.html', "Login")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `get_template_names` method instead. You don't have access to self when the class is being created

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return template_file_name(self.request, 'login.html', "Login")
```